# Lego Star Wars - TCS: How to get unlimited purple vehicle tow bombs?

Tags: lego-star-wars

In many of the flying chapters in Lego Star Wars TCS, there are purple tow bombs that you have to use to blast your way through barriers.  In the minikit guide videos, the player always has an unlimited supply of these, but I cannot figure out how to get that unlocked.

How do you get the unlimited supply of purple tow bombs.

Side question: what are those purple tow bombs actually called?
- Answer: Proton Torpedoes.

The extra is called Infinite Torpedoes.

How much does it cost once unlocked?

Comment: IIRC, you are referring to the torpedoes.

Comment: Yeah, I just found that it's called 'Infinite Torpedoes' and it's power brick 35, which is unlocked in Into The Death Star.

http://legostarwars.wikia.com/wiki/Infinite_Torpedoes
http://guides.gamepressure.com/legostarwars2theoriginaltrilogy/guide.asp?ID=1572

I don't know how much it's going to cost yet though.

Comment: According to [this FAQ](http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/971744-lego-star-wars-the-complete-saga/faqs/51249) on GameFAQs, it's 25k.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Infinite Torpeodes: In vehicle missions, generates torpedoes behind your craft (if they can carry them) for quick use.

**Cost**: 25,000;

**Power Brick**: no 35;

**Location:** VI-6 (Into the Death Star).

> This is in the core, on the left side. Get two torpedoes and torp each side of the enclosure to release it.

[Source](http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/971744-lego-star-wars-the-complete-saga/faqs/51249) (at the end of section 12A. Main Unlocks)